# Interact.js on Angular2 with DefinitelyTyped

Tags: angular, definitelytyped, interact.js

I installed interact.js angular2 in my project , but I do not know how to work with the methods described in the documentation.

My import is as follows

```
import * as _ from 'interact';
```

Is there a possibility of full service interact.js in Angular2 ? How do I create a support for drag and drop ?

DT https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/interact.js

Comment: I am using that library at this time. Here is how I imported interactjs
 .......... 'import * as interact from 'interact.js'; Then you can just interact object just like described in the Doc

Answer (score 1):

I use [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#renderer2) to select the element that you want to play with also you can pass the class name as it is and the rest of uses are quite similar to other typescript classes. Lets say the first example of interactjs, put this chunk of html into your component template

```
  <div id="drag-1" class="draggable">
    <p> You can drag one element </p>
  </div>
  <div id="drag-2" class="draggable">
    <p> with each pointer </p>
  </div>
```

And inside your component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import * as interact from 'interactjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-playground',
  templateUrl: './playground.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./playground.component.css']
})
export class PlaygroundComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private renderer2: Renderer2) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const draggableEl = this.renderer2.selectRootElement('.draggable');

    // target elements with the "draggable" class
    interact(draggableEl)
      .draggable({
        // enable inertial throwing
        inertia: true,
        // keep the element within the area of it's parent
        restrict: {
          restriction: 'parent',
          endOnly: true,
          elementRect: { top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 1, right: 1 }
        },
        // enable autoScroll
        autoScroll: true,

        // call this function on every dragmove event
        onmove: this.dragMoveListener,
        // call this function on every dragend event
        onend: function (event) {
          const textEl = event.target.querySelector('p');

          textEl && (textEl.textContent =
            'moved a distance of '
            + (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(event.pageX - event.x0, 2) +
              Math.pow(event.pageY - event.y0, 2) | 0))
              .toFixed(2) + 'px');
        }
      });
  }

  private dragMoveListener(event) {
    const target = event.target,
      // keep the dragged position in the data-x/data-y attributes
      x = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-x')) || 0) + event.dx,
      y = (parseFloat(target.getAttribute('data-y')) || 0) + event.dy;

    // translate the element
    target.style.webkitTransform =
      target.style.transform =
      'translate(' + x + 'px, ' + y + 'px)';

    // update the posiion attributes
    target.setAttribute('data-x', x);
    target.setAttribute('data-y', y);
  }

}
```

I don't think we need any other service layer to use this!